# Django ORM extract weekday as string from queryset

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

What I'm trying to do is annotate a queryset with the weekday strings (`"monday", "tuesday"` etc).

I understand how to get the int values:

```
queryset = queryset.annotate(
  weekday_int=ExtractWeekDay("date"),
)
```

But I'm having trouble getting the string values themselves. I've tried using an `ExpressionWrapper`, but `F` objects don't seem to play well with `Date` objects.

I'm using postgres as my underlying database but can't find a related `lookup_name` for the generic `Extract`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested this:

```
import calendar


class ExtractWeekDayName(ExtractWeekDay):
    @property
    def output_field(self):
        return CharField()

    def convert_value(self, value, expression, connection, context):
        v = super(ExtractWeekDayName, self).convert_value(value, expression, connection)
        try:
            return calendar.day_name[int(v)].lower()
        except (ValueError, IndexError):
            return 'error'
        except TypeError: # NoneType
            return ''
```

Seems legit.

Comment: Great answer, however [calendar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday) works `0..6` `monday...sunday` , while [`ExtractWeekday`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#extract) is 1..7 `sunday..saturday` so the return needs to be updated.

Comment: The way I did it was: `day_names_django = calendar.day_name[-1:] + calendar.day_name[:-1]`, `return day_names_django[int(v)-1].lower()`

Comment: @Darkstarone yeah cool, thanks! I'll try to digg another way. If there'll be none I will update answer with your suggestion.